# How to pass parameter (token) to another thread group , i need to use the parameter pass from another threadgroup as dynamic url

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor

[image]How to pass parameter (token) to another thread group , i need to use the parameter pass from another threadgroup as dynamic url ( as the image above , i need to use Survey Token as parameter on the next threadgroup)

i already try some tips , but still get stucked

[image]

the token passed from the result GETSurveyToken is not successful place after /svap/survey/*[token]*

hope anyone can help ??

thanks

i try using : regular expression extractor, json extractor, dan using Preprocessor to get the parameter/variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

What Regular Expression Extractor gives to you is a **JMeter Variable** so in order to be able to use it in other thread in this or other thread group you need to convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty). Once done you can access the value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

If your logic is more complex, i.e. you need to "wait" in 2nd thread group until the token is available consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)